# CCI set default username when creating a scratch org

Tags: cumulusci, github-actions

I started reading the documentation from Cumulus CI and I'm a little confused about the process to create scratch orgs. My company already has a cumulus.yml file setup for github actions but some commands of sfdx have changed syntax since when they made their setup and I'm getting some errors.
There are three specific questions about that

1. Is it possible to pass some parameter when running the `cci flow run dev_org --org dev` command to define my own username in the scratch org, or
2. Is there any way to get the scratch org's generate username from CCI after the execution of flow to use them after that in other sfdx commands?
3. You can pass additional parameters with the `-o` option but you have to specify to which specific task the command is passed to. Is it possible to pass parameters for the `sfdx force:org:create` command? Which task should I need to specify for it?